# React Table using rc-table CSS styles

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to style a table using rc-table and its className properties.

I'd like to have simply a black line as the border of the table and each cell.

When I use the border property, there is a space between each cell. When I turn off borders (border: none;), and use outline set as 1px, the border is 2px thick between adjacent cells.

Can you help as to how this can be done?

My component is defined as:

```
const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      className: 'tblColumn',
    },
    {
      title: 'Created At',
      dataIndex: 'createdAt',
      key: 'createdAt',
      className: 'tblColumn',
    },
    {
      title: 'Operations',
      dataIndex: '',
      key: 'operations',
      className: 'tblColumn',
      render: () => <a href="#">Delete</a>,
    },
  ]
...
<Table
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  className="tbl"
/>
```

My CSS styles are:

```
.tbl {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid $black;
}

.tblColumn {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid $black;
}
```